# Adobe Flex; how to cache main application

Tags: apache-flex, caching, adobe

Does Adobe Flex support caching of the main application; i.e. if the user had previously loaded it and it hasn't been modified since last loaded, can the browser get the swf file etc. from it's cache?  I'm on an embedded system with boa as the web server, so can modify any behavior there as needed.

Thanks,
Fred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if the actually is an answer to your question, but I can tell you that the browsers will cache the swf files as long as it is referenced the same way within your html.

Ie. we use src="myApp.swf?dummy=102032" when referencing to it to avoid caching. You can use httpfox or any other networking monitor tool to see when your swf is cached.

Answer (score 1):

The browser does the caching automatically just like any other file you view through it.  As long as the user has a cache setup in the browser, there shouldn't be a problem unless the URL to the file changes (that includes query strings).

There is also RSL caching, if you are using RSLs.  By default, they are just in your output folder as SWFs, but you can use the Adobe signed RSLs which are of the SWZ extension, are hosted on the Adobe site, and are cached at the Flash Player level, not the browser.  This means that even if a user has caching disabled in the browser, it will cache the RSL either way.